# How to store millions of Double during a calculation?

Tags: java, performance, data-structures

My engine is executing 1,000,000 of simulations on `X` deals. During each simulation, for each deal, a specific condition may be verified. In this case, I store the value (which is a `double`) into an array. Each deal will have its own list of values (i.e. these values are indenpendant from one deal to another deal).

At the end of all the simulations, for each deal, I run an algorithm on his `List<Double>` to get some outputs. Unfortunately, this algorithm requires the complete list of these values, and thus, I am not able to modify my algorithm to calculate the outputs "on the fly", i.e. during the simulations.

In "normal" conditions (i.e. `X` is low, and the condition is verified less than 10% of the time), the calculation ends correctly, even if this may be enhanced.

My problem occurs when I have many deals (for example `X = 30`) and almost all of my simulations verify my specific condition (let say 90% of simulations). So just to store the values, I need about `900,000 * 30 * 64bits` of memory (about 216Mb). One of my future requirements is to be able to run 5,000,000 of simulations...

So I can't continue with my current way of storing the values. For the moment, I used a "simple" structure of `Map<String, List<Double>>`, where the key is the ID of the element, and `List<Double>` the list of values.

So my question is how can I enhance this specific part of my application in order to reduce the memory usage during the simulations?

Also another important note is that for the final calculation, my `List<Double>` (or whatever structure I will be using) **must be ordered**. So if the solution to my previous question also provide a structure that order the new inserted element (such as a `SortedMap`), it will be really great!

I am using Java 1.6.

---

**Edit 1**

My engine is executing some financial calculations indeed, and in my case, all deals are related. This means that I **cannot** run my calculations on the first deal, get the output, clean the `List<Double>`, and then move to the second deal, and so on.

Of course, as a temporary solution, we will increase the memory allocated to the engine, but it's not the solution I am expecting ;)

---

**Edit 2**

Regarding the algorithm itself. I can't give the exact algorithm here, but here are some hints:

We must work on a sorted `List<Double>`. I will then calculate an index (which is calculated against a given parameter and the size of the `List` itself). Then, I finally return the `index-th` value of this List.

```
public static double algo(double input, List<Double> sortedList) {
    if (someSpecificCases) {
        return 0;
    }
    // Calculate the index value, using input and also size of the sortedList...
    double index = ...;
    // Specific case where I return the first item of my list.
    if (index == 1) {
        return sortedList.get(0);
    }
    // Specific case where I return the last item of my list.
    if (index == sortedList.size()) {
        return sortedList.get(sortedList.size() - 1);
    }
    // Here, I need the index-th value of my list...
    double val = sortedList.get((int) index);
    double finalValue = someBasicCalculations(val);
    return finalValue;
}
```

I hope it will help to have such information now...

---

**Edit 3**

Currently, I will not consider any hardware modification (too long and complicated here :( ). The solution of increasing the memory will be done, but it's just a quick fix.

I was thinking of a solution that use a temporary file: Until a certain threshold (for example 100,000), my `List<Double>` stores new values in memory. When the size of `List<Double>` reaches this threshold, I append this list in the temporary file (one file per deal).

Something like that:

```
public void addNewValue(double v) {
    if (list.size() == 100000) {
        appendListInFile();
        list.clear();
    }
    list.add(v);
}
```

At the end of the whole calculation, for each deal, I will reconstruct the complete `List<Double>` from what I have in memory and also in the temporary file. Then, I run my algorithm. I clean the values for this deal, and move to the second deal (I can do that now, as all the simulations are now finished).

What do you think of such solution? Do you think it is acceptable?

Of course I will lose some time to read and write my values in an external file, but I think this can be acceptable, no?

Comment: Just for information: The engine is **not** connected to any database.

Comment: You said when X is small the calculation ends correctly. When you increase X and the calculation does not end correctly ? Do you get any output errors ?

Comment: When brute force fails, think more. I looks like you may using monte carlo simulation methods and there is a huge literature on the subject.

Comment: What kind of distribution do the values you store have? Are many of the doubles in a given list the same value, or will they mostly be different values?

Comment: @Mark Robinson Yes, yesterday we encountered a `OutOfMemoryException`. As told in my edit, I can indeed increase the size of the memory, but I am not really happy with this solution. Note also that sometimes, my engine must handle several calculations at once...

Comment: @msw Yes, it is Montecarlo simulations ;)

Comment: @ColinD Different kind of values (amounts), but never equals to `0`.

Comment: @romaintaz I work in this field too. We use a DataSynapse (http://www.datasynapse.com) grid of machines for Monte Carlo sims. Is that feasible in your case either now or in the future?

Comment: @Dommer Don't think so. Unfortunately, this project is in production since several years, and the budgets for enhancements, especially for *technical* enhancements is really tight.

Comment: Tight budget but you have to make it do more work is the perfect time to get clever. Think of the "merge sort": I need to sort a list - which at first glance would all need to be in core at once, but memory is too small, so von Neumann invented a way to break the problem into smaller problems each of which could be solved with little core and backing store required. Your **Edit 3** pseudo-code is just a really inefficient virtual memory implementation; the key to merge sort is that each partitioning does some portion of the work. Your proposed method does not partition the work.

Comment: @msw I don't get your point regarding my 3rd edit. The idea I've explained here is just to use a temporary file to force my `List<Double>` not to store more than X elements...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you get away with using floats instead of doubles?  That would save you 100Mb.

Comment: Floating point arithmetic is not exact and would affect the calculations.

Comment: You are right Mark. However, in my experience, floats MAY sometimes be acceptable for credit risk calculations, but certainly not for front office systems.

Comment: @Mark Robinson: Your statement applies to doubles as well as floats. It is a question of whether the loss of precision matters in this particular scenario.  Only the questioner can answer that.

Comment: doubles are floats with more bits, they are no more exact than floats.

Comment: @JeremyP Good point, just saying it something to be aware of.

Comment: After some benchmarks, and tests, I will go for a `float[]` instead of a `List<Double>`. This is not a perfect solution, but for the number of elements I have to store, it is quite enough.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is algorithmic and you are looking for a "reduction in strength" optimization.

Unfortunately, you've been too coy in the the problem description and say "Unfortunately, this algorithm requires the complete list of these values..." which is dubious. The simulation run has already passed a predicate which in itself tells you something about the sets that pass through the sieve.

I expect the data that meets the criteria has a [low information content](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_theory) and therefore is amenable to substantial compression.

Without further information, we really can't help you more.

Comment: You are right. I've edited my question to add the pseudo algorithm I use.

Answer (score 3):

1. You mentioned that the "engine" is not connected to a database, but have you considered using a database to store the lists of elements?  Possibly an embedded DB such as SQLite?
2. If you used `int` or even `short` instead of `string` for the key field of your `Map`, that might save some memory.
3. If you need a collection object that guarantees order, then consider a [`Queue`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) or a [`Stack`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) instead of your `List` that you are currently using.
4. Possibly think of a way to run deals sequentially, as Dommer and Alan have already suggested.

I hope that was of some help!

---

EDIT:

Your comment about only having 30 keys is a good point.

1. In that case, since you have to calculate all your deals at the same time, then have you considered serializing your `List`s to disk (i.e. XML)?
2. Or even just writing a text file to disk for each `List`, then after the deals are calculated, loading one file/`List` at a time to verify that `List` of conditions?

Of course the disadvantage is slow file IO, but, this would reduced your server's memory requirement.

Comment: The Map will only contains 30 keys (one per deal). So I will not save anything by using another type of class...

Comment: You suggested to use a database. So I created another subject regarding this particular idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936044/how-efficient-will-be-to-use-a-in-memory-database-to-store-millions-of-temporary

Comment: Your second idea is quite the same thing that I suggested in my third edit. Maybe I will try this solution, but writing the file only every 100,000 values, not for every value in order to reduce the amount of disk I/O.

Comment: I agree, don't do 100,000 `writeLines()`.  Do one IO per `List`.

Comment: Adding a database is a bad idea. Crossing the application boundary means copying. Directly saving in the application is always faster.

Answer (score 2):

Just to clarify, do you need ALL of the information in memory at once? It sounds like you are doing financial simulations (maybe credit risk?). Say you are running 30 deals, do you need to store all of the values in memory? Or can you run the first deal (~900,000 * 64bits), then discard the list of double (serialize it to disk or something) and then proceed with the next? I thought this might be okay as you say the deals are independent of one another.

Apologies if this sounds patronising; I'm just trying to get a proper idea of the problem.

Comment: You are right, this is for financial calculations. See my edit.

Answer (score 2):

The flippant answer is to get a bunch more memory. Sun JVM's can (almost happily) handle multi gigabyte heaps and if it's a batch job then longer GC pauses might not be a massive issue.

You may decide that this not a sane solution, the first thing to attempt would be to write a custom list like collection but have it store primitive doubles instead of the object wrapper Double objects. This will help save the per object overhead you pay for each Double object wrapper. I think the Apache common collections project had primitive collection implementations, these might be a starting point.

Another level would be to maintain the list of doubles in a nio Buffer off heap. This has the advantage that the space being used for the data is actually not considered in the GC runs and could in theory could lead you down the road of managing the data structure in a memory mapped file.

Answer (score 1):

From your description, it appears you will not be able to easily improve your memory usage.  The size of a double is fixed, and if you need to retain all results until your final processing, you will not be able to reduce the size of that data.

If you need to reduce your memory usage, but can accept a longer run time, you could replace the `Map<String, List<Double>>` with a `List<Double>` and only process a single deal at a time.

If you have to have all the values from all the deals, your only option is to increase your available memory.  Your calculation of the memory usage is based on just the size of a value and the number of values.  Without a way to decrease the number of values you need, no data structure will be able to help you, you just need to increase your available memory.

Comment: Looks like we were writing similar things at the same time!

Comment: Indeed. I should have indicated that I must run all deals at the same time. See my edit.

Comment: If you need all the deals, you aren't going to be able to reduce your memory usage.  It isn't overhead of the data structure that is filling your memory, it is the values you need.  I updated my answer to include this.

Answer (score 1):

From what you tell us it sounds like you need 10^6 x 30 processors (ie number of simulations multiplied by number of deals) each with a few K RAM.  Perhaps, though, you don't have that many processors -- do you have 30 each of which has sufficient memory for the simulations for one deal ?

Seriously: parallelise your program and buy an 8-core computer with 32GB RAM (or 16-core w 64GB or ...).  You are going to have to do this sooner or later, might as well do it now.

Answer (score 0):

There was a theory that I read awhile ago where you would write the data to disk and only read/write a chunk what you. Of course this describes virtual memory, but the difference here is that the programmer controls the flow and location rathan than the OS. The advantage there is that the OS is only allocated so much virtual memory to use, where you have access to the whole HD.

Or an easier option is just to increase your swap/paged memory, which I think would be silly but would help in your case.

After a quick google it seems like this function might help you if you are running on Windows:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366537(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You say you need access to all the values, but you cannot possibly operate on all of them at once?  Can you serialize the data such that you can store it in a single file.  Each record set apart either by some delimiter, key value, or simply the byte count.  Keep a byte counter either way.  Let that be a "circular file" composed of a left file and a right file operating like opposing stacks.  As data is popped(read) off the left file it is processed and pushed(write) into the right file.  If your next operation requires a previously processed value reverse the direction of the file transfer.  Think of your algorithm as residing at the read/write head of your hard drive. You have access as you would with a list just using different methods and at much reduced speed.  The speed hit will be significant but if you can optimize your sequence of serialization so that the most likely accessed data is at the top of the file in order of use and possibly put the left and right files on different physical drives and your page file on a 3rd drive you will benefit from increased hard disk performance due to sequential and simultaneous reads and writes.  Of course its a bit harder than it sounds.  Each change of direction requires finalizing both files.  Logically something like, 
if (current data flow if left to right) {send EOF to  right_file; left_file = left_file - right_file;}  Practically you would want to leave all data in place where it physically resides on the drive and just manipulate the beginning and ending addresses for the files in the master file table.  Literally operating like a pair of hard disk stacks.  This will be a much slower, more complicated process than simply adding  more memory, but very much more efficient than separate files and all that overhead for 1 file per record * millions of records.  Or just put all your data into a database.  FWIW, this idea just came to me.  I've never actually done it or even heard of it done.  But I imagine someone must have thought of it before me.  If not please let me know.  I could really use the credit on my resume.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to format the doubles as strings and then add them in a (fast) Key Value store which is ordering by-design.

Then you would only have to read sequentially from the store.

Here is a store that 'naturally' sorts entries as they are inserted.

And they boast that they are doing it at the rate of 100 million entries per second (searching is almost twice as fast):

http://forum.gwan.com/index.php?p=/discussion/comment/897/#Comment_897

With an API of only 3 calls, it should be easy to test.

A fourth call will provide range-based searches.